# How to send the form field values to the controller using pixelcone plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to send some form field values with pixelcone fileuploader. Please suggest me for the same.

Here is my JSP fragment

```
<div id="main_container">
<form action="uploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="name"/>
<input type="hidden" name="age"/>
    <input type="file" name="pdffile" class="fileUpload" multiple />
    <button id="px-submit" type="submit">Save</button>
    <button id="px-clear" type="reset">Clear</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.fileUpload').fileUploader({
        limit : 1,
        autoUpload : false,
        selectFileLabel : 'Select',
        buttonUpload : '#px-submit',
        buttonClear : '#px-clear',
        allowedExtension : 'pdf'
    });
});
</script>
```

I need to send the form fields and then the file content to the servlet controller but I am unable to send the form fields. I am getting the file items.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include in your post the code you're working with and what you have tried. This question is far too vague for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Please help if you have the solution.

Comment: So what is `uploadfile`? What errors do you encounter in console? What is `selectFileLabel: 'Select'`, cause I do not see any `Select` elements or tags.

Comment: Also I can't find *pixelcone fileuploader* can you include a link?